# How to launch a vbYesNo message box using a powershell command with windows task scheduler

Tags: windows, powershell, task, scheduler

I am trying to create a reminder pop up using windows scheduler.

The reminder should ask a question with a yes or no button.

When the yes button is clicked a process should be started.

When the no button is clicked nothing the message box is closed.

So I have found a couple of websites that helped me

[display popup message box](https://windowsloop.com/display-popup-message-in-windows-10/)

[include hyperlink in message box](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-display-a-hyperlink-in-a-message-box/)

[start a process](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2017/02/open-website-from-powershell/)

And wrote the following code on the back of this:

```
#started with a basic popup yes no box
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms'); [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Do You Want To Open https://x.kronos.net/wfc/logon and Login to Kronos? ','Kronos Login Reminder', 4)

#then combined popup with if statement (not working so tried next line)
if([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms'); [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Do You Want To Open https://x.kronos.net/wfc/logon and Login to Kronos? ','Kronos Login Reminder', 4) -eq 'Yes') {(Start 'https://x.kronos.net/wfc/logon')}

#removed part of the code before the ; and now works
if(<#[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms');#> [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Do You Want To Open https://x.kronos.net/wfc/logon and Login to Kronos? ','Kronos Login Reminder', 4) -eq 'Yes') {(Start 'https://x.kronos.net/wfc/logon')}

#built argument that would be included windows task
powershell -WindowStyle hidden -Command "if(<#[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms');#> [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Do You Want To Open https://x.kronos.net/wfc/logon and Login to Kronos? ','Kronos Login Reminder', 4) -eq 'Yes') {(Start 'https://x.kronos.net/wfc/logon')}"

#error
#Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox].
```

Can anybody help me with some guidance on how I can achieve this at all?

I want to avoid having a separate powershell script which is why i want to contain the code in a single command that would be included in the windows task.

Comment: Do not include the `LoadWithPartialName` in the `if` condition: `powershell -WindowStyle hidden -Command "[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms'); if([System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Do You Want To Open https://x.kronos.net/wfc/logon and Login to Kronos? ','Kronos Login Reminder', 4) -eq 'Yes') {(Start 'https://x.kronos.net/wfc/logon')}"`

Answer (score 0):

As per iRON. You can also shorten the text a bit:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;if([System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Do You Want To Open https://x.kronos.net/wfc/logon and Login to Kronos? ','Kronos Login Reminder', 4) -eq 'Yes') {(Start 'https://x.kronos.net/wfc/logon')}
```

So....

```
powershell -WindowStyle hidden -Command "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;if([System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Do You Want To Open https://x.kronos.net/wfc/logon and Login to Kronos? ','Kronos Login Reminder', 4) -eq 'Yes') {(Start 'https://x.kronos.net/wfc/logon')}"
```

Comment: that's great appreciate both of your comments.